# add geolocation to jquery location picker

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation, location, picker

I'm trying to put HTML5 Geolocation in to the script attached with no luck. I would like it to find the users location when the page loads.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
        location : <input type="text"  id="us3-address" />

    raius : <input type="text" id="us3-radius" />

    <div id="us3" style="width: 550px; height: 400px;"></div>

        lat:  <input type="text"  id="us3-lat" />

       Long:  <input type="text"  id="us3-lon" />


    <script>
        $('#us3').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude: 46.15242437752303,
                longitude: 2.7470703125
            },
            radius: 300,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us3-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
            },
            enableAutocomplete: true,
            onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                // Uncomment line below to show alert on each Location Changed event
                //alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/#examples